# alignment issues with systems of eqns and list

Tags: vertical-alignment, align

I can't find the way to align equations this way[image]

And I can't align the list the way below[image]

For the list I tried this

```
\begin{flalign*}
    %\begin{equation*}
    %\begin{aligned}
    &x \tab &- \text{координата вдоль провода,}\\
    &i \tab &- \text{время,}\\
    &i(x, t) &- \text{распределение тока вдоль провода,}\\
    &v(x, t) &- \text{распределение потенциала вдоль провода,}\\
    &C \tab &- \text{ёмкость провода на единицу длины,}\\
    &G \tab &- \text{утечка на единицу длины,}\\
    &R \tab &- \text{сопротивление на единицу длины,}\\
    &L \tab &- \text{индуктивность провода на единицу длины}.
    %\end{aligned}
    %\end{equation*}
    \end{flalign*}
```

but get this[image]
Can anyone help me with pointing to some references or help to resolve it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What you try so far? Do you use `align` math environment form `amsmath` package?

Comment: @Zarko I updated my question with adding my implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part of your query, use an `align*` environment and several `array` environments. For the second part, use an `array` environment.

I would further like to suggest that you compile your document under LuaLaTeX, load the `unicode-math` package, and load suitable text and math fonts, e.g., `Stix Two Text` and `Stix Two Math`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,amsmath,amssymb,mleftright}
\mleftright

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
\setmathfont{Stix Two Math}

\begin{document}

I can't find the way to align equations this way:
\begin{align*}
\text{\large (ABC)} \quad 
   &u_{tt}=u_{xx},
    \quad 0<x<1,\\
\text{\large (DEF)} \quad 
   &\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
              u(0,t)=0,\\
              u(1,t)=\sin t,
    \end{array}\right.
    \quad 0<t<\infty,\\
\text{\large (GHI)} \quad
   &\left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}
        u(x,0)=0,\\
        u_t(x,0)=0,
    \end{array}\right.
    \quad 0\le x\le 1,
\end{align*}

And I can't align the list the way below:
\[
\begin{array}{@{} l @{\,\mbox{---}\,} >{$}l<{$} @{}}
    x & координата вдоль провода,\\
    t & время,\\
    i(x,t) & распределение тока вдоль провода,\\
    v(x,t) & распределение потенциала вдоль провода,\\
    C & ёмкость провода на единицу длины,
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. you really helped. one more thing. how to left align the list?

Comment: @mend4x - In my answer, I placed the `array` environment in an unnumbered display environment. If that's not what you want, simply replace `\[` with `\par\noindent$` and `\]` with `$`.